# SQL Count Query Including Zero Count

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns: fips, hitYear, hit. The primary key is (fips, hitYear). For every year, each county fips code appears once with a hit value of 0 or 1.

How would I develop a SQL query to get the number of times a county has a hit value of 1 within a year range, **including the counties with zero count**? The output would have the columns: fips and count.

My current query is

```
SELECT fips, Count(*) FROM (SELECT * from countyHits WHERE hit = 1) GROUP BY fips
```

but that excludes the counties with zero count.

Comment: Can you tell us what database do you use ? Also, can you show a small example of data you have and the data you expect to get. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT fips, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN hit = 1 AND hityear = 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as hits_2018
FROM countyHits
GROUP BY fips
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the values of the column `hit` are 0 and 1 then all you have to do is sum them:

```
select 
  fips, 
  sum(hit) as counter
from countyHits
where hityear = ?
group BY fips
```

Replace `?` with the year that you want the results for.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT fips,     sum(IIF(hit = 1 AND hityear = 2019,1,0) as hitYear
FROM countyHits
GROUP BY fips